# How to prove antilinearity axiom of the inner product in a linear complex space?

Tags: complex-analysis

Supppose $V$ is a complex linear space, $\psi_1$, $\psi_2$ and $\phi$ are complex vectors in $V$. Besides, $z_1$ and $z_2$ are complex numbers.
How to prove the equation below is correct?

$\langle z_1\cdot \psi_1+z_2\cdot\psi_2, \phi\rangle = z_1^*\cdot\langle \psi_1, \phi\rangle + z_2^*\cdot\langle\psi_2, \phi\rangle$

The $z_1^*$ and $z_2^*$ are the conjugates of the complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$.

Comment: What's a complex vector? Besides, axioms are not meant to be proved.

Comment: The equation you have typed is not correct.

Comment: You don't prove axioms. You use axioms to prove theorems. What are you taking as the axioms of the inner product in a complex vector space?

Comment: Would you like to clarify, Kevin?

Comment: It is my mistake to describe it as an 'axiom'. However, according to my professor, the definition of the inner product (z,w) can be both z^* w and zw^*. It's all about the definition. (Well, it's surprising that there isn't a convention...)

Comment: See https://people.math.carleton.ca/~ckfong/C5.pdf where it says $\langle x,y\rangle=\sum x_j\bar{y}_j$ but adds, "it is not clear why we prefer to take complex conjugates of components of $y$ instead of components of $x$. Actually this is more or less due to the tradition of mathematics, rather than our preference. (Physicists have a different tradition!)"

Comment: But back to your original question: presumably, you are working from such axioms as $\langle\psi_1+\psi_2,\phi\rangle=\langle\psi_1,\phi\rangle+\langle\psi_2,\phi\rangle$ and $\langle z\psi,\phi\rangle=\bar{z}\langle\psi,\phi\rangle$. It's easy to combine these to get the formula in your question.

Comment: True. I was confused by the difference between the definition given by Wikipedia and my professor. Now I suppose it's really a simple question. Thank you very much for your reply and help.